# Fisher information of a statistic

Tags: likelihood, fisher-information

I have a random sample $(X_1, X_2,...,X_n)$ and I have an estimator $\bar{X_n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$

I need to compute the Fisher information of $\bar{X_n}$. The Fisher information is defined as $-E\left(\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}logL\right)$, where $L$ is the likelihood function.

My question is: to compute the Fisher information **of the estimator** (NOT the random sample, but instead a function of the random sample), should we take the likelihood function of the random sample or the likelihood function of the distribution?

Comment: Could you tell us what you mean by a "likelihood function of [a] distribution"?

Comment: Well. The likelihood function of the random sample would be the joint distribution of the n random variables. The likelihood function of the estimator would be the probability of observing a specific value of the estimator...

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification.  Consider what the difference in $\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}\log L$ would be between the two likelihoods.

Comment: They are not always the same! Consider $f_{x_i}(x_i,\theta)=exp[-(x_i-\theta)]\cdot I_{(\theta,+\infty)} (x_i)$. The maximum likelihood estimator would be $min(X_i)$ and the two likelihood functions would be $L(X_1,...,X_2)=exp(n\theta-\sum x_i)\cdot \prod I_{(\theta,+\infty)} (x_i)$ and $L(min(X_i))=n \cdot exp(-n\cdot  min(X_i)+n \theta)\cdot I_{(0,+\infty)} (min(X_i)-\theta)$

Comment: Excellent example!  That helps me understand what you are asking.

Comment: Can you write the likelihood function out?  $L(x) = $ as a function of some $\theta$.

Comment: I noticed that the sample mean is missing the factor 1/n.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fisher information of the estimator, just the fisher information of a random sample $\theta$.

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information), it says:

> In mathematical statistics, the Fisher information (sometimes simply called information[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information)) is a way of measuring the amount of information that an observable random variable X carries about an unknown parameter $\theta$ upon which the probability of X depends.

so, it is true that fisher information is a kind of connection between two  random variables, instead of some estimator, which is a function of X.

Comment: $\theta$ is the parameter — not a sample.  The Fisher information is available before you have any examples.

Comment: As noted in the Wikipedia article you cite: "The Fisher information is not a function of a particular observation, as the random variable X has been averaged out." (From context, it is clear that by "observation," they mean the random variable computed on the sample, not any single observation in the sample.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you've got some terminology mixed up. Fisher's Information is a function of the data, just like an estimator such as $\bar{X}_{n}$ that gives you an idea of how much *information* of the parameter of interest is contained in the sample you've acquired. You can compute Fisher's Information *at* an estimator (this is usually done because the F.I. depends on the unknown parameter being estimated) and we use the plug-in estimator consisting of the F.I. evaluated at the MLE (typically).

Comment: I don't think Fisher information is a function of the data

Comment: Random variables are integrated out by expectation as we calculate the Fisher information. So it's not a function of the data; it's rather a function of the parameter.